# Prevent list from scrolling to top when hovering over a disabled listitem in select2 list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using select2 to create awesome select lists, it's a really great jQuery plugin. (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) I changed the CSS of the plugin a bit so that items which have already been selected don't disappear from the list, but just get greyed out (the also can't be selected). This working good and I selected items are still in the list after they are selected and they can't be selected again.

The problem: when a user hovers over a diabled (already chosen) item, the cursos jumps to the beginning of the list. This is really annoying, especially when working with long lists. Is there any CSS property or any JavaScript/ jQuery which makes this possible? I just want the disabled items to not react to anything when a mouse hovers over it.

Extra info: I'm using this in an ASP.NET MVC4 web application.

Here's how my selectlist looks:

```
        <select name="TopicIds" id="topDrop" multiple style="width: 700px">
            @foreach (var top in ((List<Topic>)ViewBag.TopIds).Where(top => top.MainTopic == null))
            {
                <option value="@top.TopicId" class="optionGroup">@top.Name</option>
                foreach (var subTopic in top.SubTopics)
                {
                    <option value="@subTopic.TopicId" class="optionChild">@subTopic.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Here's how the CSS class for selected items looks (I commented 'display' so the selected items get displayed):

```
.select2-results .select2-selected {
    /*display: none;*/
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: lightgrey;
}
```

How can I stop the mouse from jumping when hovering over an already selected item? Thanks!

Comment: can you post a link to an example-page? it's hard to find from these information only...
or can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's not online yet, and I think jsfiddle won't work because I need to do some modifications to the css of the plugin. Or is that possible with jsfiddle? Haven't really used it before ;)